# Python - change to different file extention

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple excel files in a folder ('folder_A') (file 1, 2, 3, etc.)

I want to import those file, do something with them (in pandas) and write the excel file to a csv file in a different folder ('updated_folder_A').

I almost got it working but for some reason it doesn't work
the files don't go ('updated_folder_A'). Can someone tell my what I'm doing wrong?

test.py:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('folder_A/*.xlxs')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)


    df['Col1'] = df['Col1'] / 60


    df.to_csv('updated_{}'.format(file), index = False)
```

Comment: According to this you're going to save the file to `updated_folder_A/[some filename].xlsx`. If you want to change the file extension, you'd have to specify a different file extension. Is that what you're asking? Your title says so, but your question itself doesn't mention file extensions.

Comment: If you are using Python 3.4+, take a look at [```pathlib```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). It will make your life easier when dealing with filenames and paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on @Anteino's answer, assuming your folder structure is like this:

- Parent folder

  - folder_A

    - file1.xlsx
    - file2.xlsx
  - updated_folder_A

Then, if your script's inside `Parent folder`, this should work:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('folder_A/*.xlxs')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)


    df['Col1'] = df['Col1'] / 60

    file = file[:-5] #Extract .xslx from file name
    df.to_csv('updated_folder_A/updated_{}.csv'.format(file), index = False)
```

Comment: Haha that's very perceptive of you! When I read your answer I also thought of a second thing. IF you're working with 97-98 excel sheets, you also have the extension .xls which is one character shorter. If there are no other dots in the filename you could write file.split(".")[0].

Comment: Good point! just because it was stated in the question that he used `xlsx`(just noticed he actually wrote `xlxs` but that doesn't exist). But for a more generic answer, that's great !

Comment: We are so smart ;p

Comment: I've got this error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'updated_folder_A/updated_folder_A\\file1.csv'

Comment: According to your error you're already inside `updated_folder_A`. In which case, change the last line to `df.to_csv('updated_{}.csv'.format(file), index = False)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to:

```
df.to_csv('updated_folder_A/updated_{}'.format(file), index = False)
```

And make sure that folder exists too.

Comment: Why am I getting negative rep for this answer? It answers the question..